# Why does using my primary key 'code_giac' for update my fields?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.7

This is my validation code in controller:

```
$request->validate([
            'libelle'=> 'required|max:50|unique:giacs,libelle,'.$giac->code_giac,
            'specif'=> 'required|max:50',
            'adlocal_1'=> 'required|max:100',
            'adlocal_2'=> 'required|max:100',
        ]);
```

I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `giacs` where `libelle` = Giac translog and `id` <> 1111)

And I don't use `id` as a primary key

Comment: Unless I am missing something the validate has NOTHING to do with the query that is being constructed and run, somewhere else in your code

Comment: specify a fourth argument as the primary key of your table here `unique:giacs,libelle,'.$giac->code_giac, primarykey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
unique:giacs,libelle,'.$giac->code_giac,
```

with:

```
unique:giacs,libelle,'.$giac->code_giac.',code_giac',
```